# Adding an action in a text input which deletes the text which the user has written

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create an "x" that appears at the end of a text input box which can be clicked to delete the text that the user has typed. I have seen this done with Angular, but I can't figure it out with HTML and CSS. I have been using the remove tag and attempting to access the value as such:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()"> X </button>
<p id="test"> </p> 
<script>
   let theText= input.value;
   function myFunction() {
       return input.value.remove();
   }
</script>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

may be you can try to replace value with null string

```
input.value = ""
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).